# Rake tast with cli arguments in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid, rake

I have created a `rake` file in my `Sinatra` app to create indexes for a `Mongodb` collection and I am trying to pass the `environment` parameter in the rake task db:create_indexes.
Here is my `db.rake` file:

```
namespace :db do
    task :create_indexes, :environment do |t, args|
        puts "Environment : #{args}"
        unless args[:environment]
            puts "Must provide an environment"
            exit
        end
        yaml = YAML.load_file("./config/mongoid.yml")
        env_info = yaml[args[:environment]]
        unless env_info
            puts "Unknown environment"
            exit
        end
        Mongoid.configure do |config|
            config.from_hash(env_info)
        end

        Bin.mongoid:create_indexes
    end
end
```

Also the `Rakefile` in the root of app contains:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}
```

But whenver I try to run the rake task using the command `rake db:create_indexes[development]`, I get the following error, `no matches found: db:create_indexes[development]`

Now I am clueless about how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was not with the code but the shell I was using.
I use `zsh` shell in place of `bash` and it seems `zsh` require you to escape the brackets: `rake my_task\['arg1'\]`.

Therefore the code works with `rake db:create_indexes\['development'\]`.